# Matlab: loading wmv video files

Tags: matlab, video, ubuntu-11.04, wmv

I am trying to load a wmv video in Matlab as follows:

```
vidObj = mmreader('video.wmv');
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
The file requires the following codec(s) to be installed on your system: video/x-ms-asf
```

I don't understand why I am receiving this error, since I am able to play wmv files on my system. I am running Matlab 7.10.0 (R2010a) on Ubuntu 11.04. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you checked to see that you have plugins-ugly installed for Gstreamer?  `mmreader` uses gstreamer See: http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2010a/techdoc/ref/mmreaderclass.html

Comment: Yes, I have the Gstreamer plugins, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it might be hard to impossible to get this working on a linux system. Alternatively, you could write your own wmv import function (if you know how to talk to the underlying libraries on your linux system, i.e. vlc).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I gave up on the problem, since it was clear that any feasible approach would be very cumbersome (if at all possible). Instead, for the problem that I was facing, I just used a windows system with Matlab to handle the loading of wmv files.

Answer (score 0):

I have received the same error message because of a version conflict for the standard c++ library.
I have started MATLAB in a console window and recognized that Gstreamer fails to load a plug-in.

```
(:26573): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstffmpeg.so': 
/usr/local/MATLAB/2010b/bin/glnx86/../../sys/os/glnx86/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by /usr/lib/libdirac_encoder.so.0)
```

The problem is, MATLAB ships with libstdc++.so.6.0.10 and GStreamer complains that it should work with libstdc++.so.6.0.13

So you should replace the symbolic link in MATLAB dir with the one in your system.

```
$ rm /usr/local/MATLAB/2010b/sys/os/glnx86/libstdc++.so.6
$ ln -s /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/local/MATLAB/2010b/sys/os/glnx86/libstdc++.so.6
```